# How to read a json string passed as command line parameter in node.js?

Tags: json, node.js

I am trying to run a script in node.js by passing a json string as a command line argument and then parsing this json string.

```
node ab.js  [{"url": "http://example"}]
```

Now in my script i do the following:-

```
var str=process.argv[2]
```

However when i try to print the variable str i am getting following output and not the whole json string.

```
[{url
```

Can some help me on this? I wanted the entire string to be stored in str variable.

Comment: Have you tried [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander)? I use it quite a lot and it handles that case perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should quote your string so that it becomes a single argument:

```
node ab.js '[{"url": "http://example"}]'
```

Alternatively you could escape the special characters that you want your shell to ignore:

```
node ab.js [{\"url\":\ \"http://example\"}]
```

Comment: be ware, add single quote might not compatible in Windows system